# Access container from service on other node in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-exec

I have Docker running in swarm mode, and created a service that runs one container. The service `my-service` runs on `node1` (Manager node), and the container `my-container` is spawned on `node2`

From `node1`, how can I make a `docker exec` on the `my-container` running on `node2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this project, [skopos-plugin-swarm-exec](https://github.com/opsani/skopos-plugin-swarm-exec), that solves my issue.

It can be used like this:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock datagridsys/skopos-plugin-swarm-exec task-exec --image <task id> <command>
```

**How It Works (Internals)**
Starting from a task ID and a command to execute, here are the steps that are taken:

- Obtain the node ID on which the target task is running, as well as the container ID of the task on that node
- Create a temporary service, using the same container image, and a scheduling constraint that places the task of the temporary service on the same node where the target task is
- Execute the equivalent of a docker exec command using the node-local Docker engine API
- Upon completion of the command, terminate the temporary service, propagating the exit code of the executed command
- Upon termination of the temporary service, extract the exit code and return it